# allowing people to send invitations for a website to their friends

Tags: facebook, fbml

I would like to allow users on my website to send invitations TO my website to their facebook
friends. What is the best way to do this?

Is there a simple snippet of FBML code I can attach to a button on my site?
Must the users first be logged into facebook?

In the developers documentation here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/req-choice/

It says "Note: You can also send requests and invites through Inbox." 
What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, the simplest way is to use [Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).  Add in the correct Open Graph tags and you will have your website published on their wall.  By using `Like`, if the person isn't logged into Facebook, it handles all of that side of things for you.

**EDIT**

http://facebook-developer.net/2008/02/20/allow-your-users-to-invite-their-friends/

**EDIT**

You said you wanted to invite people to your page.  Here is the code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>
<script>
   FB.init({ 
      appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
      status:true, xfbml:true 
   });

   FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
      message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
</script>
```

Comment: I have the like button already. I want to add a button which opens a window where a user may select one or more friends to send an invite to.

Comment: You want `Share` then.  I've tried to use this myself but failed many times.

Comment: Its unclear to me what the share button does and where any code for this is. The facebook developer documentation doesn't have information on it that I can find yet I have seen it here and there.

Comment: I thought this was the case.  I've been keeping a tag on Facebook as they seem to be moving away from the old original code.  They are moving in favour of the Social Plugins.  Not sure if there is one of those that does the same thing though.

Comment: @user427034: please see my amended answer.